# Extending parent template with same name in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I'm developing a plugin system for a new project of me. And search for a solution to extending blade templates in laravel with the same name.

To understand. I've a template `foo.blade.php` in the default laravel dir `resources/views/` and the same template `foo.blade.php` in `plugins/Foobar/Views`. And in the plugin template I make a `@extend('foo')` to extend the parent main template `foo.blade.php`. The template can find in more than one plugins use, so I have at the end of the day at example the following directory sort to find my templates:

- `plugins/Bazbar/Views`
- `plugins/Foobar/Views`
- `plugins/Helloworld/Views`
- `resources/views`

Understand what the idea is? Any solutions or ideas how can I build that?

Thanks a lot and regards

Stefan

Comment: I dont get why you dont just use a prefix? Seems like you're unnecessary complicating things

Comment: Because I don't know who is the next plugin which extend the template too. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use now Twig. And have build a simple token parser. This is for me a good solution and I can extend recursively templates in my application with plugins.